# Regex for removing more than one <a> tag in Html

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I want to get from the following html only first a tag from this html, that comes under in this `div class="itemcategories"` only and what to remove any a tag that comes after first a tag using regex only. I have no other choice, I have to do it with regex only.

```
  <div class="itemcategories">
        Categories: 
      <a id="1234" class="category" rel="abc" href="#">ABC</a>,
      <a id="1234" class="category" rel="abc" href="#">DEF</a>,
      <a id="1234" class="category" rel="abc" href="#">XYZ</a>
 </div>
```

Result should look like this

```
 <div class="itemcategories">
        Categories: 
      <a id="1234" class="category" rel="abc" href="#">ABC</a>         
 </div>
```

Comment: Don't use regex for parsing HTML. [Its a well known problem with a well known solution](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use Regex. Here is a very crude way but it should work.

```
string html = "... html goes here";
string cleanedUpHtml = html.Substring(0, html.IndexOf("</a>") + 4) + "</div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string html = ...
string rem = Regex.Match(html, "<a .+?</a>(.+?)</div>", RegexOptions.Singleline).Result("$1");
html = html.Replace(rem, String.Empty);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
var str = "" ;// Your String goes Here.
var firstPos = str.indexOf("<a");
var lastPos = str.lastIndexOf("</a>");
var regex = new RegExp("\<a.*a\>");
var firstTag = str.match(regex);
var str1 = str.slice(0,firstPos);
var str2 = str.slice(lastPos);
str = str.replace(regex, "");
str = str1 + (firstTag.toString().split(",")[0]).toString() + str2;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to this, as you can see, in the div, each a element is separated by comma, so you can try:

```
string result = Regex.Replace(your_html, ",.+</a>", "", RegexOptions.Singleline)
```

Or:

```
string result = Regex.Replace(html, "(!?,)<a .+a>(?=</div>)", "", RegexOptions.Singleline)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex:

`(<div.*?<a.*?</a>)(?:.*?</a>)*.*?(</div>)`

It will return you 2 groups. The first group will contain from the start `<div` till `</a>` at the end of the first line. The second group will contain the closing `</div>`. Just concatenate the two groups and you have what you need.